# Solving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n+b^n}{a^n-b^n}$ using squeeze theorem.

Tags: limits

I was doing this problem on limits: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n+b^n}{a^n-b^n}$$ Where $a>b>1$.
My first thought when seeing this problem was to use squeeze theorem to find the solution, so I first set the lower bound as: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n+b^n}{a^n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n+b^n}{a^n-b^n}$$

However, I was unable to find a suitable upper bound in order to apply squeeze theorem. Could somebody post a solution, or at least point me in the right direction?

(Note: I know there are much more trivial ways of solving this problem, I just want to solve it using squeeze theorem.)

Comment: Perhaps you can use $\frac{a^n+b^n}{a^n-b^n}=\frac{1+(b/a)^n}{1-(b/a)^n}=1+\frac{2(b/a)^n}{1-(b/a)^n}\leq1+\frac{2(b/a)^n}{1-(b/a)}$